# angularjs: ng-show updating before window.location.replace changes template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, redirect

I'm trying to have menus in the top side of my page to be hidden with ng-show while the login page is being shown. After the user is logged in I'm updating the variable bound to ng-show to bring forth the menus after calling window.location.replace("/"), which redirects the user to his front page.

The problem is that the scope variable which is bound to ng-show is in the same function right after window.location.replace("/") making the menu visible before the redirect completes which results in to annoying stuttering of the login form.

Is there some way to for example make the scope variable only update after the redirect is completed?

Here is my login function for reference:

```
    $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.loginError = null;
            $scope.loginLoader = true;
            $http.post('/authenticate', $scope.post)
              .then(function(res) {
                    if(res.data.success == true){
                            $scope.post = {};

                            $scope.storage.user = {};
                            $scope.storage.user.oikeudet = {};
                            $scope.storage.user.siteConf = {};
                            $scope.storage.user.ryhmät = [];

                            $scope.storage.user.accessToken = res.data.token;
                            $scope.storage.user.name = res.data.user;

                            for(oikeus in res.data.ryhmäoikeudet){
                                    $scope.storage.user.ryhmät.push(oikeus);
                                    for(id in res.data.ryhmäoikeudet[oikeus]){
                                            if(!(id in $scope.storage.user.oikeudet)){
                                                    $scope.storage.user.oikeudet[id] = res.data.ryhmäoikeudet[oikeus][id];
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            for(asetus in res.data.conf){
                                    console.log(res.data.conf[asetus].asetus);
                                    if(res.data.conf[asetus].asetus == 1){
                                            res.data.conf[asetus].asetus = true;
                                    }else if (res.data.conf[asetus].asetus == 0){
                                            res.data.conf[asetus].asetus = false;
                                    }
                                    $scope.storage.user.siteConf[res.data.conf[asetus].nimi] = res.data.conf[asetus].asetus;

                            }

                            window.location.replace("/");
                            $scope.loginmenu = '#logout';
                            $scope.loggedin = true;
                            $scope.user = $scope.storage.user;
                    }else{
                            $scope.loginerror = res.data.message;
                    }
                    $scope.loginLoader = false;
            }
         ,function(error) {
                    $scope.loginError = "Kirjautuminen epäonnistui";
                    $scope.loginLoader = false;
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the scope variable changes to a separate thread using `$timeout`. This way, the first digest cycle will be complete before executing the scope variable changes:

```js
window.location.replace("/");
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.loginmenu = '#logout';
  $scope.loggedin = true;
  $scope.user = $scope.storage.user;
});
```

You don't need to set a delay as moving it to a separate thread is enough. More info on `$timeout`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: I got it working using your sugestion, thanks! For some reason though I had to set a 1millisecond timeout because otherwise it wouldn't work.